# Google Maps Android API v2 don't show marker title

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

I tried some code to make Geocoding reverse location (using Google Maps Android API v2) and show title with marker, but the marker title didn't showed when I run my application.
Here is my code :

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

GoogleMap googleMap;
MarkerOptions markerOptions;
LatLng latLng;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    SupportMapFragment supportMapFragment = (SupportMapFragment)
            getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);

    // Getting a reference to the map
    googleMap = supportMapFragment.getMap();

    // Setting a click event handler for the map
    googleMap.setOnMapClickListener(new OnMapClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onMapClick(LatLng arg0) {

            // Getting the Latitude and Longitude of the touched location
            latLng = arg0;

            // Clears the previously touched position
            googleMap.clear();

            // Animating to the touched position
            googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));

            // Creating a marker
            markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();

            // Setting the position for the marker
            markerOptions.position(latLng);

            // Placing a marker on the touched position
            googleMap.addMarker(markerOptions);

            // Adding Marker on the touched location with address
            new ReverseGeocodingTask(getBaseContext()).execute(latLng);

        }
    });

}

private class ReverseGeocodingTask extends AsyncTask<LatLng, Void, String>{
    Context mContext;

    public ReverseGeocodingTask(Context context){
        super();
        mContext = context;
    }

    // Finding address using reverse geocoding
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(LatLng... params) {
        Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(mContext);
        double latitude = params[0].latitude;
        double longitude = params[0].longitude;

        List<Address> addresses = null;
        String addressText="";

        try {
            addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude,1);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        if(addresses != null && addresses.size() > 0 ){
            Address address = addresses.get(0);

            addressText = String.format("%s, %s, %s",
            address.getMaxAddressLineIndex() > 0 ? address.getAddressLine(0) : "",
            address.getLocality(),
            address.getCountryName());
        }

        return addressText;

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String addressText) {
        // Setting the title for the marker.
        // This will be displayed on taping the marker
        markerOptions.title(addressText);

        // Placing a marker on the touched position
        googleMap.addMarker(markerOptions);

    }
  } 
}
```

Is there a problem with my code ?

Comment: You are adding the marker twice, one when the map is clicked, and after the geocoding is complete. You should only add it when the geocoding is complete. And don't keep a class member for markerOptions. Recreate it locally in onPostCreate. I think it will be better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    GoogleMap googleMap;
    MarkerOptions markerOptions;
    LatLng latLng;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        SupportMapFragment supportMapFragment = (SupportMapFragment)
                getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);

        // Getting a reference to the map
        googleMap = supportMapFragment.getMap();

        // Setting a click event handler for the map
        googleMap.setOnMapClickListener(new OnMapClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onMapClick(LatLng arg0) {

                // Getting the Latitude and Longitude of the touched location
                latLng = arg0;

                // Clears the previously touched position
                googleMap.clear();

                // Animating to the touched position
                googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));

                // Creating a marker
                markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();

                // Setting the position for the marker
                markerOptions.position(latLng);

                // Placing a marker on the touched position
                googleMap.addMarker(markerOptions);

                // Adding Marker on the touched location with address
                new GetAddressTask().execute(latLng);
                // new ReverseGeocodingTask(MainActivity.this).execute(latLng);

            }
        });
    }

    public class GetAddressTask extends AsyncTask<LatLng, Void, Integer>{
        private LatLng loc;
        String addressText;
        @Override
        protected Integer doInBackground(LatLng... params) {
            int mFinalFlag=0;
            loc=params[0];
            String filterAddress = "";

            Geocoder geoCoder = new Geocoder(MainActivity.this, Locale.getDefault());
            try {
                List<Address> addresses = geoCoder.getFromLocation(loc.latitude,
                        loc.longitude, 1);

                if (addresses!=null&&addresses.size() > 0) {
                    Address address = addresses.get(0);
                    addressText = String.format(
                        "%s, %s, %s",
                        address.getMaxAddressLineIndex() > 0 ? address.getAddressLine(0) : "",
                        address.getLocality(),
                        address.getCountryName());
                }
            } catch (IOException ex) {
            } catch (Exception e2) {            
                e2.printStackTrace();
            }
            return mFinalFlag;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Integer result) {
        googleMap.addMarker(
            new MarkerOptions()
                .position(loc)
                .draggable(true)                                
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                .defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_AZURE))
                .title(addressText))
            .showInfoWindow();

        super.onPostExecute(result);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

change your code in `onPostExecute()`

```
googleMap
.addMarker(
        new MarkerOptions()
                .position(loc)
                .draggable(true)                                
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                        .defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_AZURE))
                .title(addressText))
.showInfoWindow();
```